# A property of the totient function

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, totient-function

Let $\ m\ge3$, and let $\ a_i$ be the natural numbers less than or equal to $\ m$ that are coprime to $\ m$ put in the following order:
$$\ a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_\frac{\phi(m)}{2}\le \frac{m}{2}\le a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}<a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+2}<\cdots<a_{\phi(m)}.$$

If $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}>\frac{m}{2}$ and $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}\ge\frac{m}{2}$ then  $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}+a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}>m$ which is wrong.

If $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}\le\frac{m}{2}$ and $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}<\frac{m}{2}$   then
$\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}+a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}<m$ which is wrong.

If $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}>\frac{m}{2}$ and $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}<\frac{m}{2}$ then $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}<a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}$ which is wrong.

So $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}>\frac{m}{2}$ or $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}<\frac{m}{2}$ is wrong, $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}\le\frac{m}{2}$ and $\ a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}\ge\frac{m}{2}$ is true, and it gives the result.

Does this proof work?

Comment: Notice that $k$ is coprime to $n$ iff $n-k$ is coprime to $n$. What does that tell you about the sequence $a_i$?

Comment: Your proof is not really a proof. You seem to have anticipated *correctly* that $a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}} + a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}$ should sum to $m$. But without justifying this, the proof is incomplete.

Comment: If we require monotonicity from $a_i$, I don't see how $a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}}>\frac{m}{2}$ can cohere with anything but $a_{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}+1}>\frac{m}{2}$.

Comment: I'm using the fact that $\ a_{\frac{phi(m)}{2}}+a_{\frac{phi(m)}{2}+1}=m $ but I'm not seeking to prove it.

Comment: I can't see the problem: I considered a proposition that leads to a contradiction in all cases so the negation gives the result?

Comment: @Plane Chon-Ju: Why not prove it?  You have not even shown that $\phi(m)/2$ is an integer.

Comment: @Phane Con-Ju : have you read my comment? You can show the property in a minute without case by case study, and without invoking $a_{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}+a_{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}+1}=n$

Comment: (+1) for all the usual reasons. Hopefully this will set a trend.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct, but you should clearly indicate where the proof starts and that you are using the result on the sum of two symmetric elements in the proof.